# Sci-fi show plot where people are killed in war based on a calculation

Tags: story-identification, warfare

A piece I was reading on just war brought to mind a plot of a sci-fi show (I believe it was a show, e.g., Star Trek, rather than a movie or book).  In this storyline, opposing warring parties would kill a certain number of their opponents troops (and maybe civilians?) based on calculations (possibly a war game scenario) in an antiseptic environment (i.e., the killing was never seen).  I believe that the resolution came when the warring leaders were forced to confront each other physically.  Can anyone help me nail this show down?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: To whoever voted to close: The question is general reference only if you know beforehand that the show in question is Star Trek.  If you don't know, then figuring it out the answer is a bigger task because you'd have to also consider hundreds of _Twilight Zone_ and _Outer Limits_ episodes plus other sci-fi dramas on TV that might have contained the story.

Comment: Sorry Kyle, that was me. I removed my notes once I was told about the general reference choice being discussed. Then the person who told me removed his response so you didn't know we talked about it. Sorry...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simulated wars with real casualties](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/172967/simulated-wars-with-real-casualties)

Comment: @amflare I see you took my advice, however, unfortunately there is no acceptance on this answer, so we can't mark as dupe at this point. See [Closing Story-Ident questions as duplicates (where there's no acceptance)](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7067/21267)

Comment: Since story identification questions are about identifying a story based on specific criteria, wouldn't it only make sense to close them as dupes if the identification criteria were identical?  I can easily imagine a scenario in which one is web searching and might benefit from both answers existing so as to be more likely to catch key phrases that were entered into the query.

Comment: @DarrenRinger - Our agreed policy is to only close where there's an acceptance on both. Simple,  clean, easy to administer. Don't forget that they'll still show up, just one redirects to the other.

Answer (score 24):

#### The answer to your question is the star Trek, The Original Series episode '[A Taste of Armageddon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Taste_of_Armageddon)'.

The Enterprise becomes part of a dispute between two worlds who use computational technologies to wage a war in which civilians are escorted to liquidation centers as casualties of war. The civilizations indicated they preferred this to actual warfare since there was less collateral damage. Captain Kirk, in order to save his ship and crew and in a [violation of the Prime Directive](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Prime_Directive#Exceptions), forces both civilizations to consider engaging in actual combat to bring back the horror of war and to consider an actual peace rather than their "computerized warfare".

NOTE: The violation of the Prime Directive is the Enterprise's continued incursion into the Ameniar star system after being told by the residents to NOT enter their space. The Federation is forced to give Kirk an exemption because they sent a diplomat to the system with the express intention of stopping the computerized warfare and saving the thousands of lives lost every year.

> "A Taste of Armageddon" is a first-season episode of Star Trek: The Original Series. First broadcast on February 23, 1967 and repeated July 20, 1967, episode #24, production #24, and was written by Robert Hamner and Gene L. Coon, and directed by Joseph Pevney. --**Source: Wikipedia**

Comment: Kirk didn't violate the Prime Directive here. The Enterprise was drawn into the middle of a war and Kirk fought back. The civilization was advanced, Warp-capable, and aggressive and so they deserved the hardball treatment that they received.

Comment: Kirk does violate the Prime Directive and is given an exemption to it. A Taste of Armageddon is listed on Memory Alpha as one of the exemptions. (Compliance with specific (and valid) orders that could not be followed if the Prime Directive fully applied (e.g., ancillary to a war with the Federation; first contact missions; diplomatic missions; trade negotiations) (TOS: "Errand of Mercy", "Spectre of the Gun", "A Taste of Armageddon", "Friday's Child"; TNG: "First Contact"; DS9: "In the Pale Moonlight")